Attempting to use a Crafting Table in a world where my addon is active causes Minecraft to hang with Event 1002 (on Windows 11). Why is this?
When I activate my addon, the vanilla Crafting Table becomes unusable. Interacting with it starts to bring up the GUI, but it's transparent and doesn't load fully, and then Minecraft freezes completely. Looking at the Event Viewer afterwards shows an "Event 1002: Application Hang" error.
Removing only the 'Recipes' folder from the behavior pack fixes the problem, so the error seems to be caused by something to do with a custom recipe or recipes.
Unlike the issue discussed here on Reddit, this affects a singleplayer world and happens consistently every time the crafting table is used.

This can be caused by a circular reference between two or more different files in a pack's 'Recipes' folder.
In non-technical terms, you've most likely switched around two recipes with regards to their respective file names/recipe identifiers. (This is very easy to do when copying & pasting from a template!) Double-check that the identifier within each recipe .json file is correct and unique.

For example, the following configuration:
> BP/Recipes
    carved_luminous_quartz.json
    chiseled_luminous_quartz.json


Inside 'carved_luminous_quartz.json':

{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "packname:chiseled_luminous_quartz"
        },
    
        "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
        ...etc.


Inside 'chiseled_luminous_quartz.json':

{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "packname:carved_luminous_quartz"
        },
    
        "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
        ...etc.

will consistently cause the error described in your question.

Correcting the mixed-up names/identifiers:
> BP/Recipes
    carved_luminous_quartz.json
    chiseled_luminous_quartz.json


Inside 'carved_luminous_quartz.json':

{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "packname:carved_luminous_quartz"
        },
    
        "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
        ...etc.


Inside 'chiseled_luminous_quartz.json':

{
    "format_version": "1.20.50",
    "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "packname:chiseled_luminous_quartz"
        },
    
        "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
        ...etc.

fixes the problem, and the crafting table will work normally again.
